# C# check if download upload bytes greater then

Tags: c#, visual-studio, network-programming

I have dialer program in C#. I wanted to change image if download / upload is in progress. How can I add such check in following code?

```
private void UpdateNetworkInterface()
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            NetworkInterface nic = nicArr[cmbInterface.SelectedIndex];
            IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = nic.GetIPv4Statistics();
            long lngBytesSent = 0;
            long lngBtyesReceived = 0;
            int bytesSentSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesSent - lngBytesSent) /1024;
            int bytesReceivedSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesReceived - lngBtyesReceived) /1024;
            // Update the labels
            lblInterfaceType.Text = nic.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString();
            lblUpload.Text = bytesSentSpeed.ToString() + " KB";
            lblDownload.Text = bytesReceivedSpeed.ToString() + " KB";
            //this.StatusTextBox.AppendText(string.Format("{0}\r\n\r\n DOWNLOAD/UPLOAD in progress", ""));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those property gives you the total bytes transferred, what you need is the derivative of that number (The rate of change).

The easiest way is just do the simple math problem

So you will need to recordings then compare those two points to get the speed.

```
private long _lastBytesRecevied;
private long _lastBytesSent;
private DateTime _lastReceivedMesurement;
private DateTime _lastSentMesurement;

//This needs to be done once at the start of the class to "seed" the first value.
private Init()
{
    _lastReceivedMesurement = DateTime.UtcNow;
    _lastBytesRecevied = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;

    _lastSentMesurement = DateTime.UtcNow;
    _lastBytesSent = interfaceStats.BytesSent;
}

private double getKBDownloadSpeed()
{
    double result = (interfaceStats.BytesReceived - _lastBytesRecevied) / (DateTime.UtcNow -  _lastReceivedMesurement).TotalSeconds;

   _lastReceivedMesurement = DateTime.UtcNow;
   _lastBytesRecevied = interfaceStats.BytesReceived;

   return result / 1024d;
}

private double getKBUploadSpeed()
{
   double result = (interfaceStats.BytesSent - _lastBytesSent) / (DateTime.UtcNow - _lastSentMesurement).TotalSeconds;

  _lastSentMesurement = DateTime.UtcNow;
  _lastBytesSent = interfaceStats.BytesSent;

   return result / 1024d;
}
```

Now your two functions returns the average download speed between the last time the function was called and the current call.

If you get value in download speed, change the image as download icon.
If you get value in Upload speed, change the image as upload icon.

Sincerely,

Thiyagu Rajendran

**Please mark the replies as answers if they helps.

Comment: Gr8. But I am very new to programming thing. please pardon me.
Where should I put the above code in which section?

Comment: variables into the global variable section(Variables within the class not in method). Copy the code from Init() to your UpdateNetworkInterface and add 2 lines in it. var averagedownspeed = getKBDownloadSpeed(); var averageupspeed = getKBUploadSpeed(); copy 2 methods within your class. make your IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats variable as global variable **don't forget it.

Comment: Its a working code for me. If it works for you, please go ahead and mark it as answer to help other programmers to locate this answer.

Comment: I tried pasting it, but getting different errors. this is because the code i have made is now mixed up , tok it from various resources and somehow made it worked. can you pelase take a look at code, I pasted it at pastebin. http://pastebin.com/hHretcj4

Comment: Your code must be refracted properly. It messed up I tried to make the necessary changes I can. http://pastebin.com/7U2psdx4

Comment: Change private DateTime  _lastMesurement to public in top of the code. Make sure you have imported DateTime reference.

Comment: Getting error:
`Error 5 The name '_lastMesurement' does not exist in the current context `

Comment: & how can i show these getKBDownloadSpeed & getKBUploadSpeed in label to show avg transfer ?

Comment: You will get the values in var averagedownspeed and averageupspeed. Keep a bugger and check it. assign the value to label as strings.

Comment: Ok I am getting `NaN` value in label/textbox window. maybe its not picking the right speed? updated code is here. http://pastebin.com/EP3QmPps

Comment: You have to update labels continuously using timer. Your code run only one time intial value will be Nan so, its not reflecting in your UI.  lblUpload.Text = averageupspeed.ToString() + " KB";
                lblDownload.Text = averagedownspeed.ToString() + " KB";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138917/discussion-between-thiyagu-rajendran-and-syed-jahanzaib).

Comment: Mr. Thiyagu Rajendran gave me very detailed guide but unfortunately it didn't worked out for me & This is purely dueto my lack of knowledge .for now I really have to understand the basics before making more annoying any1 here .
I tried another code and it worked for me. although accuracy is not correct, but i hope i will overcome on it. thx mr  Thiyagu Rajendran.

Comment: `
`int sent_Speed = (int)(status.BytesSent - lngBytesSend) / 1024;
int receive_speed = (int)(status.BytesReceived - lngBtyesReceived) / 1024; 
            int bytesReceivedSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesReceived - lngBtyesReceived) / 1024;

            l2.Text = (sent_Speed).ToString() + " KB/s";
            l1.Text = (receive_speed).ToString() + " KB/s"; 
            lngBytesSend = status.BytesSent; 
            lngBtyesReceived = status.BytesReceived;
 `

Comment: You are welcome buddy! Good to see you are trying hard to learn it . Soon you will succeed in it good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Net.WebClient` to do it.

it has an event `DownloadProgressChanged` and it has parameters and it has fields that contain downloaded bytes and total bytes of the file.

It is fired by `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync()`.

MSDN Link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Example :

```
private void DownloadChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    labelProgress.Text = string.Format("{0} Percents Completed",
                 e.BytesReceived / e.TotalBytesToReceive * 100);

}

private void StartDownload(object sender, EventArgs e) // Button Event
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadChanged);
    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(/* URL */);
}
```

Getting upload bytes is same as Download one. Happy Programming! :)

Comment: WebClient , this will be useful if i wanted to test the bandwidth via downloading any file. where as my real query was how to monitor network interface traffic in per seond value, like donwload xx KB/S in real time